# Only first item in listbox is added to table in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form where I have to loop through selected items in a listbox and add those ID's to the database. What's happening though is that it's looping through x times the number of items I select, but it only adds the ID number of the first item in the listbox regardless of what other items I selected (and the first item is not selected. My code is below:

```
' Loop through each selected item and add that to the Eng_Topic lookup table
For Each varItem In Me.Res_Topic_ID.ItemsSelected

    StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Eng_Topic (Eng_ID, Res_Topic_ID) VALUES (" & lastID & ", " & Me.Res_Topic_ID.ItemData(varItm) & ")"
        DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
        Debug.Print StrSQL
        Next varItem
    End Sub
```

Any help is appreiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) at the top of each module.
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time.

To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.
This is really a must have for VBA development.

It will then tell you that `varItm` in `Me.Res_Topic_ID.ItemData(varItm)` is undeclared - because it should be `varItem`.

That's why you always get the first item from the listbox.